# JQuery - append em elemento gerado por prepend em um each

Tags: jquery

Como faço para adicionar elementos em um elemento que foi adicionado dentro de um each ? Segue exemplo:

```
            $.each(data.id, function(i, item) {
                $( ".lado" ).prepend("<div id='tes'>" + data.id + "</div>");

                if (data.id == i) {
                    $( "#tes" ).append("<div>" + data.id + "</div>");
                }

            });
```

O prepend dá certo mas aparentemente o append não dá certo pois eu não acho o id adicionado no prepend.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer assim:

```
$.each(data.id, function(i, item) {
  var tes = $("<div id='tes'>" + data.id + "</div>");// guarda o novo elemento dentro de uma var
  $(".lado").prepend(tes); // usar o novo element
  if (data.id == i) {
    tes.append("<div>" + data.id + "</div>"); // já está disponível para appends
  }
});
```

Só uma coisa, caso queira capturar o elemento atual dentro do *loop*, deve usar, ao invés do `data.id`, o próprio `item` que passou como argumento. No caso ficaria assim:

```
$.each(data.id, function(i, item) {
  var tes = $("<div id='tes'>" + item + "</div>"); // guarda o novo elemento dentro de uma var
  $(".lado").prepend(tes); // usar o novo element
  if (item == i) {
    tes.append("<div>" + item + "</div>"); // já está disponível para appends
  }
});
```

Num sei se é isso que quer, mas fica aí caso seja.

Comment: Está certo o que fez, mas como ele gerou o código, tem que trabalhar com o `$.(document)`, senão, não achará as posições.

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino, olhe esse fiddle  e inspecione os elementos: https://jsfiddle.net/8p788u6w/1/ . Como o novo elemento está na variável, as posições são encontradas. Era disso que falava?

Comment: Nesse exemplo, o `id` é o mesmo para todos, o resultado sairia maquiado.

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino, é um exemplo rsrs. Coloquei três ids iguais aos `index` do loop para mostrar a eficácia do `append`. Mas de qualquer forma, esperemos o AP retornar para ver se o serviu. Se achar que algo está realmente errado poderia ser mais específico?